# stub a file in Rails sprockets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

I'm trying to stub a custom JS file I made, and I end up with a bunch of errors. What am I doing wrong?

**application.js**

```
//= stub "pantalla.js"
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require font_awesome5
//= require timepicker
//= require imageviewer
//= require imagemap
//= require charactercount
//= require trix
//= require_tree .
```

I tried:

- Changing the order
- using simple quotes
- removing '.js' and so on

Of course, If I remove the stub line all works, but what I'm trying to do is to not load this page specific piece of JS everywhere.

[image]

Comment: Did you try witout extension and quotes?

`//= stub pantalla`

Comment: yes, tried that